# Web Forms - Repeater's Enum Display Value

Tags: asp.net, enums, webforms

I have a list of objects that I want to bind to a repeater (not necessarily displayed in a table format) using the following code:

C# object code:

```
public enum CategoryEnum
{
    [Description("Entertainment and Film")]
    EntertainmentFilm = 1,
    [Description("Audio and Music Cover")]
    AudioCover = 2,
    [Description("Others")]
    Others = 0
}

public class Document
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public CategoryEnum Category { get; set; }
}
```

Web Forms code:

```
        <asp:Repeater id="listDoc" runat="server" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:Label id="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'/></td>
                    <td><asp:Label id="lblCategory" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Category") %>'/></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Is there a way to display the results as

> **Name**  |   **Category**
>   music1  |   Audio and Music Cover
>   movie1  |   Entertainment and Film
>   movie2  |   Entertainment and Film
>   series1 |   Entertainment and Film
>   sports  |   Others

Instead of:

> **Name**  |   **Category**
>   music1  |   AudioCover
>   movie1  |   EntertainmentFilm
>   movie2  |   EntertainmentFilm
>   series1 |   EntertainmentFilm
>   sports  |   Others

Or is there a better approach for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static class EnumHelper<T>
   {
       public static string GetEnumDescription(string value)
       {
           Type type = typeof(T);
           var name = Enum.GetNames(type).Where(f => f.Equals(value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).Select(d => d).FirstOrDefault();

           if (name == null)
           {
               return string.Empty;
           }
           var field = type.GetField(name);
           var customAttribute = field.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
           return customAttribute.Length > 0 ? ((DescriptionAttribute)customAttribute[0]).Description : name;
       }
   }

var movieDesc = EnumHelper<CategoryEnum>.GetEnumDescription("EntertainmentFilm");
var audioDesc = EnumHelper<CategoryEnum>.GetEnumDescription("AudioCover");
var othersDesc = EnumHelper<CategoryEnum>.GetEnumDescription("Others");
```

Above is an example to show how you can get description from your Enum value. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can add these 2 members in your "Document" class. One is the read only property that gets the category value and calls the second member the static function that uses reflection to get the description of enum:

```
public string CategoryDescription
    {
        get
        {
            return GetEnumDescription(this.Category);                                
        }
    }

public static string GetEnumDescription(Enum value)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

        DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
            (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
            typeof(DescriptionAttribute),
            false);

        if (attributes != null &&
            attributes.Length > 0)
            return attributes[0].Description;
        else
            return value.ToString();
    }
```